# Filter expanded OData request

Tags: sapui5

I need to pass a parameter to the backend. I want to use $filter for this.
My code below is not working, there are no filters returned by `io_tech_request_context->get_filter( )->get_filter_select_options( )` in the `Figures` entityset.

```js
var aFilters = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("TeamMembers/Figures/FILTERKEY", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,   sFilterValue) ];

this.getView().bindElement({
    path: "/TeamDataSet('0')",
    parameters: {
     expand: 'TeamMembers/Figures'
    },
    filters: aFilters
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Element binding / [ContextBinding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataContextBinding) doesn't support the property `filters` since you're binding just a single entity and not a collection. If you need to filter `Figures`, you'll have to bind them to an aggregation (e.g. `items` on [List](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/aggregations)), get the corresponding [ListBinding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding) object, and then call [`.filter`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding/methods/filter) from there.

Here is a similar example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/AoIZI4/](https://embed.plnkr.co/AoIZI4/?show=controller%2FHome.controller.js,preview). Take a look at the handler `onSearch`.

---

In case someone actually wants to filter a list by expanded results, the navigation property can be applied in the Filter path which then gets resolved by the path of the bound binding object. For example:

```
<List items="{
  path: 'myODataModel>/Products',
  parameters: {
    expand: 'ToSupplier'
  }
}">
```

Then in Controller, filter `Products` by their supplier country:

```
new Filter({
  path: "ToSupplier/Country",
  operator: "EQ",
  value1: "UK",
})
```

(From: [https://embed.plnkr.co/wAlrHB/](https://embed.plnkr.co/wAlrHB/?show=view/Home.view.xml,preview)).

Be aware that this works only if expanding does **not** result in a collection but a single object (e.g. associated supplier). Filtering by looking up at an associated *collection* is supported as of OData V4 which can be achieved via [`FilterOperator.All` / `.Any`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator/properties).

Comment: I am actually trying to filter my result set with Odata v2, but I am getting an error `Unknown filter property`, nevertheless my expanded association is a single object.

Comment: @zygimantus Is the issue still relevant? If true, please open a new question with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'll take a look there.